# Bad layout of first post on election in mobile browser

Tags: bug, moderator-election, design

What's wrong with first post in the election on mobile? I see this:

[image]

It's only the first post that is bad. The rest are readable.

- Device Android KitKat
- Browser Chrome 71.0.3578.99

Comment: Which device/browser?

Comment: What browser, what device? I can't reproduce this on iPhone 8plus with Chrome, Safari or Firefox, nor can I get anything like it using the responsive tools for Firefox on my desktop.

Comment: I managed to reproduce this with Chrome (desktop) with the iPhone 5/SE setting (320x568). My suggestion: rotate to landscape mode.

Comment: And I see the effect when the window is at 345 pixels or narrower, and your exact rendering at 317 width.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes indeed it's narrower than 345px